# Nextflow flatmap not executing as expected

Tags: groovy, workflow, nextflow

I have a dictionary "data". And I need to parse a key, value pair to a process. The end result should look like:

```
carcode=somename
params={minimum=3000, ignore=60, maximum_A=2500, maximum_B=500}
carcode=somename2
params={minimum=5000, ignore=100, maximum_A=3500, maximum_B=22500}
```

I have written this code and it works with a hardcoded value and not with the variable "it" I'll point to it in the code.

```
data = [
    "a" : "A",
    "b" : "B",
    "c" : [
        "somename":[
            "z" : "Z",
            "y" : "Y",
            "params" :[
                "minimum": "3000",
                "ignore": "60",
                "maximum_A": "2500",
                "maximum_B": "500"
            ]
        ],

        "somename2":[
            "z" : "Z",
            "y" : "Y",
            "params" :[
                "minimum": "5000",
                "ignore": "100",
                "maximum_A": "3500",
                "maximum_B": "22500"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

carcodes = Channel.from(data.c.keySet())
transform_carcodes = carcodes.flatMap { it ->  [it] }
//HERE
results = transform_carcodes.flatMap { it ->  [barcode: it, params: data.c."somename".params] }
//HERE
results.subscribe onNext: { println it }
```

Currently the output gets the proper keys but uses the value of the hardcoded key:

```
carcode=somename
params={minimum=3000, ignore=60, maximum_A=2500, maximum_B=500}
carcode=somename2
params={minimum=3000, ignore=60, maximum_A=2500, maximum_B=500}
```

Why doesn't it work when I do `params: data.c.it.params`?

I get the output: `Cannot get property 'params' on null object`

I have tried `toString(it)`

Also once I get the output, how can I pass this k/v pair to a process, and spawn a new process for each k/v pair?

```
process{
    container "python:3"

    script:
    """
    python3 some_file.py <key> <value>
    """
}
```

When run this process should spawn:

```
python3 some_file.py somename {minimum=3000, ignore=60, maximum_A=2500, maximum_B=500}
python3 some_file.py somename2 {minimum=3000, ignore=60, maximum_A=2500, maximum_B=500}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Nextflow, this is how I managed to handle this issue:

The trick is to use `c[it]` and not `c.it`

```
carcodes = Channel.from(data.c.keySet())
transform_carcodes = carcodes.flatMap { it ->  [it] }
results = transform_carcodes.flatMap { it ->  [ [it, data.c[it].params] ] }

process A{
    echo true

    input:
    set x,y from results

    script:
    """
    python3.7 run_me.py ${x} \'${y}\'
    """

}
```

run_me.py

```py
import sys

print("First:")
print(sys.argv[1])
print("Second:")
print(sys.argv[2])
```

And the output:

```
[15/aec54c] process > A (1) [100%] 2 of 2 ✔
First:
somename
Second:
[minimum=3000, ignore=60, maximum_A=2500, maximum_B=500]

First:
somename2
Second:
[minimum=5000, ignore=100, maximum_A=3500, maximum_B=22500]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do `data.c.it.params` the `it` is treated as yet another key in your nested map. As soon as no such key exists, you get a null for the `params` key.

The code to build your desired result could look like

```
def data = [....]

data.c.each{ k, v -> 
  "python3 some_file.py $k {${v.params.collect{ "$it.key=$it.value" }join(', ')}}".execute().text
}
```

each string is rendered as

```
python3 some_file.py somename {minimum=3000, ignore=60, maximum_A=2500, maximum_B=500}
python3 some_file.py somename2 {minimum=5000, ignore=100, maximum_A=3500, maximum_B=22500}
```

Comment: mhm. Well how do I fix it?

Comment: So I had this before I looked into flatmap. How can I pass these values to my process? `params = Channel.from(result)` and then in my process if I do `input: val x from params` I get the output: ```[af/d5fa1c] process > A [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[:]```

Comment: Looks like you just need to run a couple of commands based on your `data` structure without collecting any intermediary results. Hence the code in update

Comment: This is groovy code correct? Cause Nextflow works off inputs and outputs. I need each k/v pair to be an input to a process. Look (here)[https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/example.html] for a quick example of a Nextflow workflow to highlight process/inputs/outputs/script

Comment: updated... I was thinking that the `params` should've beed json, now they are printed in the format you need

Comment: Can we convert the json to a bunch of lists like shown here?
```tuple = Channel.from( [1, 'alpha'], [2, 'beta'], [3, 'delta'] )

process setExample {
    input:
    set val(x), file('latin.txt')  from tuple

    """
    echo Processing $x
    cat - latin.txt > copy
    """
}```

Comment: don't make an off-topic session here, nobody really knows anything about nextflow or whatever (the tag has 19 questions only including this one). The groovy code I given leads to the results you desired

Comment: Bro your code does work, no doubt about that. But in my question I have mentioned I need to pass the k,v pairs to a process and not run the python function myself. It is not off-topic at all, your answer went off-topic when you solved the problem using groovy and didn't take into consideration I was talking about Nextflow. Anyway, thank you for trying.

Comment: dude did you try out the code? it DOES exactly what you described. `"...".execute().text` spawns a command-line process as per https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#execute()

Comment: Yes bro! I did. And I have already upvoted and told you it is correct. But Nextflow handles the spawning of processes, I cannot use this code since I need to "pass inputs to a process" and not spawn the process myself.

Comment: obviously you have 2 different questions: how to prepare the arguments? AND how to spawn the process? You had problems with the 1st part, now you have to sort out the 2nd and that should be done in another question of yours

Comment: Have a look at the edit, it was essentially one question with two parts. And is now solved.